# Java execute a application in specific session

Tags: java, linux, psexec, winexe

I am invoking a application on windows xp, 7 machines from remote linux using winexe. But I am not able to execute the application in foreground it executes in background. I tried psexec but no success. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the application under the same user which is loged on on the windows-machine and use start @ beginning of the cmd command.